# Data.List.NonEmpty.toNonEmpty

Tags: haskell

I can not import
`Data.List.NonEmpty.toNonEmpty`
but yet it's in the doc at
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmptyList-0.0.9/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html

I am thinking of just copying it locally from the source at
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmptyList-0.0.9/docs/src/Data-List-NonEmpty.html

Comment: Same problem with `unsafeToNonEmpty`

Comment: How are you trying to import it? Can you show your code? Are you using the right version of the package?

Comment: I found https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html which has isomorphic `nonEmpty` instead.

Comment: There is no package -- it's in `base`

Comment: problem solved with the latter

Comment: @Kwaggy what was the problem??? the latter what?

Comment: It's not in base. Your links clearly point to package `NonEmptyList-0.0.9`

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html (aka _the latter_) is in base, and I am using `nonEmpty`.

OTOH https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmptyList-0.0.9/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html is clearly outdated, as there is no `toNonEmpty` for my `import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE` (I did not touch cabal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you are looking at the documentation for the [`NonEmptyList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmptyList) package, but actually importing that module from the `base` package. If that's so, you can read the correct documentation [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html). Use `ghc-pkg list base` to find out if you should navigate to the documentation for a different version of the `base` package.

...of course, with any discrepancy there's two fixes; in this case, the other fix would be to add the `NonEmptyList` package as a dependency in your project's cabal configuration files. You'll likely need [package-qualified imports](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/package_qualified_imports.html) to make that work correctly.